# Using GDB in a virtual machine to debug Python ctypes segfaults

Tags: python, gdb, virtual-machine, ctypes

I have been working on a project that has been working fine on a dedicated Linux CentOS system.

The general idea is that there is a Python workflow manager than calls shared libraries written in C using ctypes. It works fine.

However, the need for me to have a local instance of the project for development purposes has come up. I set up a Linux Mint virtual machine with VMWare under Windows 7. For the most part, everything works fine.

The problem is one module is crashing with a segmentation fault upon calling a function in one of the shared libraries. Normally this is OK, and on the dedicated Linux machine, using something like "gdb python corename" lets me see exactly where it crashed and work the problem out.

However, with the local setup I am having problems. The thing I notice most is that GDB does not report correct memory addresses. It's a huge project so I can't post all the code, but I'll give a rundown:

Python module creates a "file_path" variable, a string. It first passes this to a certain shared library to load the file. If I execute the command, in python

```
hex(id(file_path))
```

it will return something like '46cb4ec'. In the first shared library, which is C, I start it out with

```
printf("file_pathaddress = %x\n", &file_path[0]);
```

and it outputs 'file_path address = 46cb4ec', which is the same as I get through Python's 'id()' function. I guess this is expected...?

Anyways.. I send this same variable to another shared library, but it crashes immediately on this call. If I analyze the core file, it shows it crashes on the function call itself, and not a line within the function. The strange thing, though, is it outputs something like:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x00007f124448c9fc in seam_processor (irm_filename=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff5fab51b8>, 
seam_data_path=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff5fab51b0>, 
    full_data_path=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff5fab51a8>, ranges=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff5fab51a0>, 
    job_id=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff5fab519c>, job_owner=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff5fab5198>, 
    y_tile_in=1, x_tile_in=1, fc_int=10650000000, atmos_props=..., surf_props=..., extra_props=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff5fab5190>, 
    gascalc_ftype=513, len_gas_sectrum=16, vect_spec_fq=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff5fab5188>, surfscat_theta_inc_vector_size=6, 
    surfscat_theta_inc_vector=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff5fab5180>, surfscat_phi_inc_vector_size=6, 
    surfscat_phi_inc_vector=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff5fab5178>, surfscat_theta_scat_vector_size=6, 
    surfscat_theta_scat_vector=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff5fab5170>, surfscat_phi_scat_vector_size=6, 
    surfscat_phi_scat_vector=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x7fff5fab5168>) at src/seam_processor.c:47
```

So, what I can't figure out is why GDB is reporting these memory addresses as such. In this case, the 'irm_filename' variable is what the Python passed in as 'file_path', so its address should be what the other library and the id() function report, 0x46CB4EC. Why is it different? However, the strange thing is that some of the variables are just fine, like 'y_tile_in'. If I do in gdb:

```
(gdb) print &y_tile_in
$1 = (int *) 0x7fff60543f80
```

So, although it can read this memory address, this is not the same as what Python's id() would report, or what a similar C printf() of the address would report in a library that doesn't crash. Also, these memory addresses are really big numbers, larger than the amount of memory I have by far... What do they really mean?

My question, then, is what exactly is going on here? Is the fact that this is being run in a virtual machine doing this? Is there some mapping going on? I haven't been able to find anything online about something different I'd have to do if using gdb in a virtual machine, so I'm at a loss...

Anyone know what's going on?

Thanks.

*EDIT*

So, the problem has gotten stranger. Basically, I commented out all the code from the library that does anything and left the function call the same. When I do this and run it in gdb with a breakpoint, all of the memory addresses that it prints in the function call are normal, match the Python id() function and match printf() on the addresses.

I started un-commenting out code to see what the problem could be. The problem is with a declaration:

```
double nrcs_h_d[MAX_NINC_S*MAX_SCAT_S];
double nrcs_v_d[MAX_NINC_S*MAX_SCAT_S];
```

If I comment out both lines, there is no crash. If I comment out only the second line, there is no crash. If no lines are commented out, though, it crashes.

The strange thing is that MAX_NINC_S and MAX_SCAT_S both equal 500. So, these arrays are only a couple of megabytes in size... Elsewhere in the code arrays of several hundred megabytes are allocated just fine.

Also, if I replace the above lines with:

```
double *nrcs_h_d, *nrcs_v_d;
nrcs_h_d = (double *)malloc(MAX_NINC_S*MAX_SCAT_S*sizeof(double));
nrcs_v_d = (double *)malloc(MAX_NINC_S*MAX_SCAT_S*sizeof(double));
```

It seems to work fine... So apparently the problem was related to trying to allocate too much on the stack.

So, the questions become:

Why does gdb not show this is the line of the code where the segmentation fault happens, but instead says it is the function call?

Why do the memory addresses of the core dump file seem to get all screwed up if that allocation is made?

Thanks.

Comment: segfault on win7 machine only or both? What version of c compiler you used to compile the c module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that stack space grows downward, while heap space grows upward; addresses close to the top of your virtual memory space (e.g. `0x7fff5fab51b0`) are stack-allocated variables, while addresses closer to the bottom (e.g. `0x46cb4ec`) are heap-allocated variables. Note that virtual memory space is usually much, much larger than physical memory; it looks like your operating system and architecture support up to 128 GiB of virtual memory.

Since Python depends heavily on dynamic memory allocation, it will end up putting its objects on the heap, which is why `id()` tends to return addresses on the low side. If C code copies any values to stack-allocated variables and subsequently tries to call functions using those local copies, you'll see addresses on the high side again.

There is a line number provided: `src/seam_processor.c:47`. <strike>Is there anything interesting there?</strike> The various memory addresses that GDB is complaining about are various memory addresses *on the stack*, all of which are sequential, and almost all of which themselves appear to be pointers (since they are all 8 bytes wide).

(This is the best answer I can give with the information at hand; feel free to suggest revisions or provide additional information.)

Comment: Thanks. The line number is just the line of the function declaration, which is why it was difficult to track down what was causing the error. Because gdb was showing all those invalid memory addresses and the fact that it said it was crashing at the line of the function declaration rather than the line in which that array was being allocated misled me.

Comment: @user1601315 All right. Are things working now? Let me know if you need anything else cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that the allocation of data for local variables in a function occurs before any code in a particular function is executed.

The compiler works out the amount of required stack space and allocates it before getting to the statements in the function. So the actual execution of your function goes a bit like this:

1. Allocate the amount of storage for all local function variables,
2. Start executing the statements in the function

In that way, when you call another say function2 from fucntion1, the local variables of function1 will not be disturbed with data from local variables in function2.

Thus in your case, the space required for your local data variables is more than the stack has available and the exception is raised at a point in time before the function code starts executing.